# What does the message "Publishing has been disabled for this archive" mean for a PPA on Launchpad?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

On a launchpad ppa page such as [this one](https://launchpad.net/~khnz/+archive/ppa), what does the message "Publishing has been disabled for this archive" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it isn't building on any supported versions.  The last build revision was on O, so everything it built for is no longer supported.

Comment: That is what it seems like, to me as well. Does this also mean that one cannot install the PPA in question? Or, can you also run a `sudo add-apt-repository` against the PPA even though the warning exists?

Comment: @Kevin: I actually tried that.  It adds the repository all right, but then the `update` command produces some errors (404 and such like).  In other words, it's just as though the packages aren't really there.

Comment: If you HAD to use the tool in question you could add it, edit the ppa line in apt/sources.list.d/ and change the dist name.  Then pull the source package.  Then rebuild for your current dist and see if it works.