# How do I add a gpg key and ppa for mozillavpn without using apt-key or add-apt-repository?

Tags: apt, vpn, ppa, gnupg

I want to install mozillavpn without using apt-key or add-apt-repository because using those methods leads to deprecation warnings every time you run `sudo apt update`. If you follow the Mozilla VPN download link for the Linux download, it takes you so a support page with installation instructions at the page titled [How to install Mozilla VPN on a Linux computer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-install-mozilla-vpn-linux-computer).

TLDR: Found the problem (not solvable?):
[What does the message "Publishing has been disabled for this archive" mean for a PPA on Launchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345720/what-does-the-message-publishing-has-been-disabled-for-this-archive-mean-for-a) . This is likely the cause for the 400 errors and such.

What I've done so far. I found Ubuntu's [Launchpad profile page](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillacorp). On that page, just below 'OpenPGP keys:' is the key fingerprint. You can find their public key at keyserver.ubuntu.com , either by logging into launchpad.net (when logged in, the fingerprint on Mozilla's launchpad profile becomes hyperlink to the keyserver page) or you can search the key fingerprint at keyserver.ubuntu.com and it takes you right to the same page.

Based on a comment by eddygeek at this [askubuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291035/how-to-add-a-gpg-key-to-the-apt-sources-keyring), and with the key fingerprint (starting with 506556...), I tried this command: `sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/mozilla-vpn.gpg --recv-keys 50655629D846C1040AA480DA5BD2CCE6C5567242` , which outputs

> gpg: keybox '/usr/share/keyrings/mozilla-vpn' created
> gpg: failed to create temporary file '/root/.gnupg/.#lk0x000055cfe4208850.pc1.6829': No such file or directory
> gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/root/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
> gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr

From the errors, I figure I need to create /root/.gnupg , so I:

```
sudo su
cd /root
mkdir .gnupg
chmod 700 .gnupg
```

I exit root to normal user, run 'sudo apt update', whose output includes the errors:

> Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E51560313C444E0
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E51560313C444E0
> E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I looked at the manpage for apt-secure but it looks like instruction for creating the gpg files.

Ideally I'd like to find a couple simple commands, like the [three commands to install vivaldi](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/install-update/manual-setup-vivaldi-linux-repositories/) using gpg instead of add-apt-repository. Any suggestions?

Edit: I was suggested [solutions on this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key). The wget command doesn't work with the link that (I think) is the public gpg file (the one I discussed at keyserver.ubuntu.com). Instead of wget, if I manually copy the contents of the [link](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x50655629d846c1040aa480da5bd2cce6c5567242) into a file (say mozilla-vpn.gpg) and try this command:

```
cat ~/Desktop/mozilla-vpn.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/mozilla-vpn.gpg
```

My understanding is that you have to use the 'gpg --dearmor' command because the first line of the original gpg file actually identifies it as a pgp file instead. So 'gpg --dearmor' converts it to gpg and then it's piped to /usr/share/keyrings/mozilla-vpn.gpg . I can do that and follow it with:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mozilla-vpn.gpg arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy main" | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillacorp-mozillavpn-jammy.list
```

but when I `sudo apt update` , I still get a very similar error:

> Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E51560313C444E0
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E51560313C444E0
> E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillacorp/mozillavpn/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Also, when I use the `file mozilla-vpn.gpg` command, I don't get the expected output as is in the suggested link. Instead of `PGP public key block Public-Key (old)` I get `PGP public key block Secret-Key`

Is this indicating the problem?
The file's first line is '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----' so it seems to be the public gpg file.

If I try to do the import/export explained on the suggested solution page, the export command output is : `gpg: WARNING: nothing exported`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What commands (exactly) should replace the deprecated apt-key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key)

Comment: @ArturMeinild If I use the keyserver.ubuntu.com file url with wget,  I get a wget 'error 400'. (It's not a straight link to the file... its a link like https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=5065(bla,bla,bla). And if I try to copy the contents of the public key into a file on my computer, and then use 'file <keyfile>', the output is not the same as expected from you link. Instead it's: PGP public key block Secret-Key

Comment: Also try the gpg options I have used in https://askubuntu.com/a/1295145/158442

Comment: [What does the message "Publishing has been disabled for this archive" mean for a PPA on Launchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345720/what-does-the-message-publishing-has-been-disabled-for-this-archive-mean-for-a)